# What are .co files in JavaScript ecosystem

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

There's a mutagen wrapper here: https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/mutagen.js

It consists of src/main.co file which doesn't look familiar in any way. What kind of technology is this? Extension *.co is not searcheable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's coco - CoffeeScript dialect](https://github.com/satyr/coco).

It also embeds of Python snippets, writes them out as scripts and then executes as subprocess.

Comment: Thanks! Is it really alive?

Comment: Check Github latest commits (check all branches), check issue tracker and decide by your own criteria of "alive" :)